# how list actually works in python using for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I tried this code, I don't understand how it works

```
a=[1,'a',2,'b','test','exam']
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

output

```
1
a
2
b
test
test
```

Comment: how it iterate through list like that? @L_Church

Comment: the loop is using the last element of `a` to store the loop variable. Very weird if you ask me. So `exam` is lost forever since the first iteration.

Comment: can you explain in brief? @Jean-FrançoisFabre with example??

Comment: The weirdest thing is that "a" as a result will get content: [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'test'], even though it never explicitly changed or attached any value.

Comment: @NandishPatel It seems like you've found something that has stumped us for once. That's why this is being upvoted a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's change the loop a little:

```
a=[1,'a',2,'b','test','exam']
for temp in a:
    a[-1] = temp
    print(a[-1])
```

This loop does the same.

All iterations:

```
temp = a[0]     => a[-1] is 1       and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test',1]
temp = a[1]     => a[-1] is 'a'     and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test','a']
temp = a[2]     => a[-1] is 2       and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test',2]
temp = a[3]     => a[-1] is 'b'     and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test','b']
temp = a[4]     => a[-1] is 'test'  and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test','test'] 
temp = a[5]     => a[-1] is 'test'  and a is [1,'a',2,'b','test','test']
```

Focus on the last 2 iterations.

Answer (score 6):

In python you can access the last element of a list implicitly by using the index `-1`. So `a[-1]` will return the value of the last element of the list `a`.

By doing the for loop `for a[-1] in a`, you iterate through the list, and store the value of the next element of `a` in its last element.

So to better understand what's going on, you should print the whole list at every iteration, so you can visualize the operation:

```
a=[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'exam']
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a)
```

You will get:

```
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 1]
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'a']
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 2]
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'b']
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'test']
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 'test', 'test']
```

You can see that at every iteration the last element will hold the value of the upcoming element, and actually you will lose the original content of the last element, i.e. `'exam'` as it's getting overwritten in every iteration.

Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: thanks you code has the same meaning but his answer is quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Clobbering. for a[-1] in a sets a[-1] = a[1] because of the for loop. In the subsequent iterations, it does that again, so the contents of the list cycle. When it does the 6th iteration, you might be expecting the print to be "exam." However, remember what happened in the first iteration. a[-1] = a[1]. The exam string no longer exists, because it was clobbered by the integer 1. At that time, both a[1] AND a[-1] are the integer 1.

After the for loop completes, you exit its scope. In the main program's scope, the contents of the list a never changed. So your print at the end is irrelevant to what happened in the loop.

The for loop accepts all the same assignment targets a regular assignment does, no matter how silly. So it's assigning to the last position of the list repeatedly.

You really shouldn't use any indexing between for ... in. You should just write a variable name there, and don't write the name of any existing variable. No one would write code like this in a real project because for loops are not supposed to be used like this.

Comment: I accidentally stumbled upon it.